# How to execute a multiple value parameter function in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to execute a function which has a parameter with multiple value.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE(MyFunction('1,2'));
```

This is how I created function

```
create or replace FUNCTION MyFunction
(
  -- Add the parameters for the function here
  Ids varchar2
)

--
//Extra bit and pieces
```

If I create single value function,

```
create or replace FUNCTION MyFunction
(
  -- Add the parameters for the function here
  p_party_id IN NUMBER
)
```

And execute like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE(MyFunction(1));
```

Then above query works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

The function you created with

```
create or replace FUNCTION MyFunction
  (
  -- Add the parameters for the function here
  Ids varchar2
  )
```

still only takes one parameter. If you want to pass in multiple parameters you need to declare each one, as in:

```
create or replace FUNCTION MyFunction
  (
  -- Add the parameters for the function here
  Id_1 varchar2,
  Id_2 varchar2
  )
```

Best of luck.

Comment: I am struggling to execute multiple value parameter like select * from emp where emp_id in (1,2,3,4,5); In the given function above i still need one parameter only but it's a multiple value parameter. Hope that make sense. :)

Comment: Ah, I see. It appears you're trying trying to pass a list of values in a string that you will then use in an `IN` clause. Put simply, you can't do that. Sorry.

Comment: I'd say you can, @Bob - takes a little bit of *typing*, but - you can do that. Have a look at my example in this discussion, splitting that comma-separated values list into rows. Such a query can then be used as a subquery for the IN clause.

Answer (score 1):

Aha, so you're passing a comma-separated values as a parameter. If that's so, you'll have to *split* it into rows and do *something* with separate values.

Here's an example which returns the input string as rows and joins then with the `DEPT` table (owned by Scott). You might want to do something different with it.

```
SQL> create or replace function myfunction(par_ids in varchar2)
  2    return sys.odcinumberlist
  3  is
  4    t_id sys.odcinumberlist := sys.odcinumberlist();
  5  begin
  6    select regexp_substr(par_ids, '[^,]+', 1, level)
  7    bulk collect into t_id
  8    from dual
  9    connect by level <= regexp_count(par_ids, ',') + 1;
 10
 11    return t_id;
 12  end;
 13  /

Function created.

SQL> select x.column_value, d.dname, d.loc
  2  from dept d join table(myfunction('10,20,30')) x on x.column_value = d.deptno;

COLUMN_VALUE DNAME          LOC
------------ -------------- -------------
          10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
          20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
          30 SALES          CHICAGO

SQL>
```